# Can we schedule a job to load json file from GCS to MongoDB on GCE

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

We have vision API data getting stored in firestore. There is a job in place that copies firestore data to google cloud storage and then loads it to bigquery.
Now since the data gets copied to google cloud bucket and I also need a job to load same data from bucket to MongoDB which is hosted on GCE. Is it possible?
I am very new to GCP. I managed to launch MongoDB on GCE. I am able upload/download files to mongoDB through SSH, also through gcloud from local. But I want this loading to be automated through job.
Can someone help to advise on this?

Comment: Several questions. 1. How do you trigger your current job (load from storage to BQ)? 2. How do you ingest the file with Mongo? Do you have a special process for this? Or the file format is compliant with Mongo and ingested automatically? 3. Can you trigger your mongo load job through API (even if it's a MongoDB API)?

Comment: I have a question, how your current process to upload/download is working? I mean, is it a batch or script file? Or are you doing it manually? may be possible to execute it in a cron job, but it depends on how it works